# Retriving the count from one table given a value from another

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to obtain a value from one table and use that to run count() on another table.  *I've searched through other questions/answers for help in solving my problem but there isn't one that I've been able to adapt to my scenario in SQLite.*

This my code after a unfortunate number of attempts:

```
c.execute("""SELECT MonkeyHouse.BananaType, count(*)  
FROM MonkeyVillage 
JOIN MonkeyHouse 
   ON MonkeyVillage.BananaType = MonkeyHouse.BananaType 
GROUP BY MonkeyHouse.BananaType""")
```

So I'm trying to obtain the BananaTypes from the MonkeyHouse and check how many of these BananaTypes are in the MonkeyVillage (and not combined total with the MonkeyHouse).

My code will select the BananaTypes from the MonkeyHouse, but when it returns the count from the MonkeyVillage some counts are accurate while others are not.

How do I solve this?

**Update**

Values Present in MonkeyHouse (attempting to use the IPs to search the MonkeyVillage)

```
(u'10.0.0.10') - x1 (records exist)
(u'10.168.77.10') - x2 (records exist)
(u'192.168.77.190') - x1 (records exist)
(u'33.0.0.3') - x1 (records exist)
```

Values Present in MonkeyVillage (excluding other IPs)

```
(u'10.0.0.10') - x1 (records exist)
(u'10.168.77.10') - x3 (records exist)
(u'192.168.77.190') - x1 (records exist)
(u'33.0.0.3') - x2 (records exist)
```

My code returns:

```
(u'10.0.0.10', 1)  - Successful match
(u'10.168.77.10', 6)  - Unsuccessful 
(u'192.168.77.190', 1) - Successful match
(u'33.0.0.3', 2)  - Unsuccessful
```

Comment: I've modified your code block to prevent scrolling. Please provide your table values so that we can attempt to replicate this. Without that data, we can't determine why it is accurate for some and not others.

Comment: _"some counts are accurate while others are not"_ Accurate compared to what? Are they off by one or two, or _waayyy_ off? We definitively need some [minimum concrete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to really figure whats going on. Maybe a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data provided, and assuming you are joining on the IP address, the results looks correct for the query.  When you join between two tables, your results will be the number of records in table 1 times the number of matching records in table 2, so your numbers are being multiplied.

Assuming the "x2" means 2 records exist for the IP address, and you only want a count of results from the MonkeyVillage table, you may want to try an "IN" clause on the MonkeyVillage table.

```
c.execute("""SELECT MonkeyVillage.BananaType, count(*)  
FROM MonkeyVillage
WHERE MonkeyVillage.BananaType IN (
SELECT MonkeyHouse.BananaType
FROM MonkeyHouse)
GROUP BY MonkeyVillage.BananaType""")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!! (I'll add clarification to the original post regarding the count from just the MonkeyVillage, thanks :)